# GoogleMaps API Macro/VBA Not Returning DriveTime & DriveDistance Anymore

Tags: vba, google-cloud-platform, google-maps-api-2

I had the following macros that created a formula in Excel where I could link two addresses and get either the drive distance or drive time.

e.g., `=GetDistance(A1,B1)*0.000621371` <- b/c it came in Meters so converted to miles
e.g., `=GetDuration(A1,B1)/3600` <- b/c it came in seconds so converted to hours

Here are the two macros.  Does anyone know why they're not working anymore.  My guess is that google changed the path slightly to access them but I don't know enough about VBA or GoogleMaps API to fix it so pardon my ignorance

**Get Google Maps distance (in meters)**

```
Public Function GetDistance(start As String, dest As String)
    Dim firstVal As String, secondVal As String, lastVal As String
    firstVal = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="
    secondVal = "&destinations="
    lastVal = "&mode=car&language=pl&sensor=false&key=*MyKey*"
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    URL = firstVal & Replace(start, " ", "+") & secondVal & Replace(dest, " ", "+") & lastVal
    objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objHTTP.send ("")
    If InStr(objHTTP.responseText, """distance"" : {") = 0 Then GoTo ErrorHandl
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp"): regex.Pattern = """value"".*?([0-9]+)": regex.Global = False
    Set matches = regex.Execute(objHTTP.responseText)
    tmpVal = Replace(matches(0).SubMatches(0), ".", Application.International(xlListSeparator))
    GetDistance = CDbl(tmpVal)
    Exit Function
ErrorHandl:
    GetDistance = -1
End Function
```

**Get Google Maps duration (in seconds)**

```
Public Function GetDuration(start As String, dest As String)
    Dim firstVal As String, secondVal As String, lastVal As String
    firstVal = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="
    secondVal = "&destinations="
    lastVal = "&mode=car&language=en&sensor=false&key= *MyKey*"
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    URL = firstVal & Replace(start, " ", "+") & secondVal & Replace(dest, " ", "+") & lastVal
    objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objHTTP.send ("")
    If InStr(objHTTP.responseText, """duration"" : {") = 0 Then GoTo ErrorHandl
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp"): regex.Pattern = "duration(?:.|\n)*?""value"".*?([0-9]+)": regex.Global = False
    Set matches = regex.Execute(objHTTP.responseText)
    tmpVal = Replace(matches(0).SubMatches(0), ".", Application.International(xlListSeparator))
    GetDuration = CDbl(tmpVal)
    Exit Function
ErrorHandl:
    GetDuration = -1
End Function
```

Did some research in Google Maps Platform documentation but can't seem to find the path.

Comment: "not working" is not a very useful description of exactly what happens when you run your code.  Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Check the content of `objHTTP.responseText`. Does it contain any useful information or some error (I get an invalid API Key which is not a surprise as I don't have any key). If not an error: Does it contain the regex pattern you are searching?

Comment: @TimWilliams - It used to return the drive distance and drive time.  It no longer does.  No error message.  Just doesn't return a value.  It either does or doesn't so that's where the not working came from.  My hunch is that GoogleMaps changed the internet path so the firstval is off.  That happened a few years ago where I had to change the http to https for some reason.  It's either something like that or the browser version might have been phased out.  I don't know man... I'm not an IT guy which is kind of why I'm here lol.

Comment: I don't have an API key for google maps, so I can't test...

Comment: I get a response for `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Newark,NJ&destinations=New+York,NY&mode=car&language=pl&sensor=false&key=*MyAPIKey*`.   What is the URL your code is using?  What values are you using for `origins`/`destinations`?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, see the code below. The real issue was the ErrorHandl call.

```
Public Function GetDistance(start As String, dest As String)
Dim firstVal As String, secondVal As String, lastVal As String
firstVal = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="
secondVal = "&destinations="
lastVal = "&mode=car&language=es&avoidTolls=True&key=*MyKey*&v=3.50"

Set ObjHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

Url = firstVal & start & secondVal & dest & lastVal

ObjHTTP.Open "GET", Url, False
ObjHTTP.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
ObjHTTP.Send ("")

Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp"): regex.Pattern = """value"".*?([0-9]+)": regex.Global = False
Set matches = regex.Execute(ObjHTTP.responseText)
tmpVal = Replace(matches(0).SubMatches(0), ".", Application.International(xlListSeparator))
GetDistance = CDbl(tmpVal)

End Function
```

Remember to update your API Key :)